# Assign title value to input field in wordpress posts loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to assign a value to a specific input field in a WordPress loop.
I am showing all the posts in a category in a single page and the category has several posts. Each post has a booking form which when a button is clicked, it pops up.
I am using contact form 7 which is called via do_shortcode() function inside the category template. When for example a form is clicked on 'post 1', there should be a hidden field with the value 'post 1', if 'post 2' is clicked, value of the hidden field should be 'post 2' as well.

I have a category which has posts that I'm looping through via the_loop.
Each post has a title and a form. What I want to achieve is within that category, the title of the post is assign to the corresponding input field.

However, the title of the last post is being assigned to the input of the other posts

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <script>
    var title="<?php the_title(); ?>";
        jQuery( ".itinerary-title-class" ).each(function( i ) {
        jQuery(this).attr('value', '<?php the_title(); ?>');
    </script>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I want versus what I get. Please assist.
[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery to do this? The result of your code above will be to create a separate script on each pass through the loop where each changes the `value` of all items with `.itinerary-title-class` to the current post title. Check your browser's console, but my guess is only the first script is running. You need to rethink your approach to this. Post your full form generation code, and I might be able to give you some suggestions.

Comment: @cpilko Thank you for your comment. I know my approach isn't the best but I just need  a way to push a the title of the corresponding input field. If you have a better idea, I would really appreciate.